# Wireless network disconect every x time in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, 15.04, connection

my wifi network suddenly disconnects with out a reason.
I didn't have this problem with older ubuntu versions, once I updated to ubuntu 15.04 the wifi started to crash.
Someone had the same problem or knows what may be so I can fix it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the make & exact model number of your wireless card (Broadcom/Intel/Realtek/etc)?

Ubuntu has a number of open unresolved bugs related to WiFi issues. Depending on the make of your card, one of these could be effecting you:

1. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1354975
2. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/266033
3. https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83641

Also, given that this issue didn't exist before you upgraded to 15.04, it may be similar to the following problem where the Wifi driver and the bluetooth driver were interfering with each other: https://askubuntu.com/questions/547365/intel-centrino-iwlwifi-driver-problem-wifi-disconnects-after-suspend-hibernate

Comment: I don't have bluetooth in my notebook, maybe the problem started when I bought another router and connected them in bridge. Could that be the problem?

Comment: My wireless card is a Realtek RTL8188CE

Comment: Possibly an issue with the bridge. Revert back to the original setup (of using a single router) and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: i can't revert back beacause I use the other router to have wireless connection in all my house

Comment: it would help to eliminate all potential external variables before mucking about with driver updates in Linux. I suggest you try using a SINGLE WIFI router that is connected directly to your ISP. This way you will be able to determine if the issue is with your Router, or if it indeed an issue with Ubuntu on your laptop.